# Issues with SPI to UART Communication using MAX14830 EVKit and Raspberry Pi

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, uart, spi

I'm working on a project where I'm using the **MAX14830 EVKit** to bridge communication between a **Raspberry Pi (SPI interface)** and another device **(UART interface)**. The goal is **to have the main machine to be able to communicate over multiple UART channels via this EVKit**.

Here's a breakdown of my setup:

Raspberry Pi: Connected to the MAX14830 via SPI.

Other Device(Jetson Orin): Connected to the MAX14830 via UART pins.

I've followed the standard procedures from [this documentation](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX14830.pdf) and have set up the necessary configurations on both the Raspberry Pi and the EVKit, but I could not manage to see the communication output on both sides.
I am using [this](https://github.com/rm-hull/spidev-test) to test my SPI connection and it works as I see if I plug off the power supply of the EVKit, script returns 0.

Here is the image of my setup:
[image: Setup Photo]

Left side is connected to SPI COntroller Interface(Raspberry Pi) and on the right Jetson Orin is connected as one of the UART clients.

**Here is my questions in order:**

1- Is there any problems on my setup?

2- Should I explicitly listen devices from /dev folder to see messages in terminal on both sides?

3- Is there any kind of resources I can use for this EVKit? I am struggling to find any useful resource for this and datasheet is not efficient as I thought it would be. Also I am computer science based engineer so I might not be efficient too.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have connected all grounds? (Please [edit] your question, don't post a comment, this is not a forum.)

Comment: @thebusybee gorund for 24v is connected and it is only power supply. do I need any other to be gorunded

Comment: You have three components, therefore three grounds. All of them need to be connected (in your case).

Comment: yeah raspberry pi and jetson orin are grounded

Comment: now I got what you saying and connect them all to a shared ground

Comment: nope @thebusybee thanks for helping I gave up working on this